# Converting text with HTML tags to formatted text in Word using VBA

Tags: html, vba, ms-word

[Boxes with question mark from page breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFdMw.png)
I want to modify text in Word with HTML tags to change it to Word-recognized format.

I am looking to modify the code below to include the following:

1. Format everything to a specific size and font (Calibri size 11 for example).
2. Recognize line breaks tags (<br>) to swap with an actual line break.
3. Not just recognize bold or underline, but instances where both are used simultaneously.

```vb
Sub ReformatHTML()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        ' Remove <p>
        .Replacement.Text = "\2"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(p\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Replacement.Text = "\2"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(u\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Replacement.Font.Underline = True
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(strong\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Replacement.Style = "Strong"
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(i\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(h\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        ' line break
        .Replacement.Text = vbCrLf
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<br\>"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code works, aside from the modifications. Post titled [Rendering text with HTML tags to Formatted text in a Word table using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360632/rendering-text-with-html-tags-to-formatted-text-in-a-word-table-using-vba) has helped.

Here is a sample of text I am trying to modify (I can't figure out how to do it with text and not have the HTML converted to formatting):
[image]

Comment: Why not simply view in a browser and then copy and paste into Word merging formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pleas try.

```
Sub ReformatHTML()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Format = True
      .Forward = True
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      ' replace <u>
      .Replacement.Text = "\2"
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      ' set font style
      .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
      .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
      .Text = "\<(u\>)(*)\</\1"
      .Replacement.Font.Underline = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      ' line break
      .Replacement.Text = vbCr
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "\<br\>"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> remove tag <p> and integret with code on OP

```
Sub ReformatHTML()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        ' Remove <p>
        .Replacement.Text = "\2"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(p\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Replacement.Text = "\2"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(u\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Replacement.Font.Underline = True
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(strong\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Replacement.Style = "Strong"
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(i\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<(h\>)(*)\</\1"
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 11
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        ' line break
        .Replacement.Text = vbCrLf
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<br\>"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Set font style for whole document, then `.Replacement.Font.Name` and `.Replacement.Font.Size` are not necessary.

```
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
    End With
```

Comment: THank you so much. That has me a little closer. I tried including your code along with what I already had, but I am still confused. I edited my post to include a screenshot of the kind of text I am dealing with. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to paste just text without stack overflow converting the HTML tags to the actual formatting. Also, there are some characters (<p>, </p>) that I cannot seem to get rid of.

Comment: please double check your sample doc. the first </strong> is overlap w/ <p> tag. Do you want to remove all p tag?

Comment: Thank you, taller_ExcelHome. The first </strong> overlap with <p> is just somethign that happened because the users are doing lots of updating in Excel, which is troubling and they won't listen to me. But, yes, I would like all the <p> tags removed as they don't seem to matter for this task. When I tried removing them, only the "p" would be removed but the "</>" characters would stay. Not sure why?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I made a tweak and pasted over my code above to be able to make the whole document Calibri size 11. The only thing left is in all the instances where there is a page break, the break spacing looks right; however, what is left behind are boxes with a question mark inside. I will include another screenshot above titled "Boxes with question marks from page breaks."

Comment: If you `make the whole document Calibri size 11`, then you don't need set `.Replacement.Font`.

Comment: Oh, good point. I will remove all of that code. Any idea on why I am getting the boxes with question marks left behind?

Comment: Change `vbCrLf` to `vbCr`

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. Can I Venmo you $ for your trouble? I am so very thankful (project is to help a colleague, but still...)

Comment: Mark the reply as an  answer if it solves your question. It's helpful for SO users.